# Обновить таблицу из другой

Tags: sql, foxpro

Есть таблица `uslugi` с полями `idsluch, vz, vz_mo`
Также есть таблица `sluch` с полями `id, mo`

Как обновить в таблице `uslugi` поле `vz_mo` значением `sluch.mo`, но только для тех услуг где поле `uslugi.vz = 1`?

Сами таблицы связаны так: `sluch.id = uslugi.idsluch`

Comment: Как вариант `UPDATE Uslugi SET vz_mo = S.mo FROM (SELECT * FROM Sluch) S WHERE vz = 1 AND idsluch = S.id;`

Answer (score 0):

Для БД oralce сработает запрос

```
update uslugi u set u.vz_mo = (select s.mo from sluch s where s.id = u.idsluch)
where u.vz=1
```

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).